# Acer E15 e5-73g-56rg fail to install ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I tried to install ubuntu 14.04 on acer e 15 from USB. it boot successfully, but when I select the option to install ubuntu, the screen goes to black, and doesn't react.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any error message during installation ?

Was the installation process under pink color as usual ?

I'd suggest you should try again but with a DVD containing Ubuntu 14.04 (easy to get from a windows PC a burnable and bootable DVD via Image Iso free utility.

Laurent06000

Comment: There is not any error message.  It's not under pink color, it is under black color. I saw from other article that it is because the UEFI.